# I'm having an issue with pygtk

Tags: python, pygtk

Hello all I've been learning python and pygtk I've recently run into an issue with a small program i was trying to make.

When you click the tray icon the first time my window appears as normal but after closing the window which I tried to set to be like a "minimize to tray" type thing it won't open again only display a blank window instead of the one it shows originally.

```
    import os
    import gtk
    import gobject
    import datepicker
    from dateutil import relativedelta
    import datetime
    import numberentry
    class ShutdownTimer:
        tray_tooltip = ''
        timer_visible = False
        timerui = gtk.Window()
        def set_tooltip(self, string):
            self.tray_tooltip = str(string)
        def set_visible(self, v, visible):
        self.timer_visible = visible
        if self.timer_visible is True:
            self.timerui.show_all()
        else:
            self.timerui.hide_all()
        def set_up(self):
            self.timerui.set_title("Shutdown Timer")
            self.timerui.connect("destroy", self.set_visible, False)
            self.row_one = gtk.HBox()
            self.combo = gtk.combo_box_new_text()
            self.combo.append_text("Shutdown")
            self.combo.append_text("Hibernate")
            self.combo.append_text("Suspend/Sleep")
            self.combo.append_text("Restart")
            self.combo.append_text("Cancel")
            self.combo.set_active(0)
            self.row_one.pack_start(self.combo, False, False)

            hlbl = gtk.Label()
            mlbl = gtk.Label()
            hlbl.set_text("H:")
            mlbl.set_text("M:")

            self.hentry = numberentry.NumberEntry()
            self.mentry = numberentry.NumberEntry()
            submit = gtk.Button("Submit")
            submit.connect("clicked", self.submit_action)

            self.row_one.pack_start(hlbl, False, False)
            self.row_one.pack_start(self.hentry, False, False)
            self.row_one.pack_start(mlbl, False, False)
            self.row_one.pack_start(self.mentry, False, False)
            self.row_one.pack_start(submit, False, False)

            self.row_one.show_all()

            self.timerui.add(self.row_one)


        def submit_action(self, action):
            task = self.combo.get_active_text()
            hours = int(self.hentry.get_text())
            minus = int(self.mentry.get_text())
            hourm = hours * 60
            tmins = minus + hourm
            tseconds = tmins * 60
            print tseconds

            date = datetime.datetime.now()
            print date

            future = datetime.timedelta(seconds=tseconds)
            total = date+future
            print total

            print "%s scheduled for %s" % (task, total)
            string = task + " scheduled for " + str(total)
            md = gtk.MessageDialog(self.timerui, gtk.DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT, gtk.MESSAGE_INFO, gtk.BUTTONS_CLOSE, string)
            md.run()
            md.destroy()
        #print '%s - %s / %i:%i %s' % (action, date, hours, minutes, timePart)
        #date_split = date.split("/")
        #today = datetime.date.today(date_split[2],date_split[0], date_split[1])
        #rd = relativedelta(today, datetime.date())
        #print "Seconds to go: %(seconds)d" % rd.__dict__
        def on_right_click(self, shutdown, status, action):
            menu = gtk.Menu()

            menu_item = gtk.MenuItem("Quit")
            menu_item.connect("activate", lambda w: gtk.main_quit())
            menu.append(menu_item)
            menu_item.show()
            menu_item = gtk.MenuItem("Show Window")
            menu_item.connect("activate", self.set_visible, True)
            menu.append(menu_item)
            menu_item.show()
            menu.popup(None, None, None, action, action)
        def __init__(self):
            self.status = gtk.StatusIcon()
            home = os.getenv('HOME')
            icon_path = home + '/.config/shutdowntimer/icons/32x32/tray_icon.png'
            settings_path = home + '/.config/shutdowntimer/settings/'
            self.status.set_from_file(icon_path)
            self.status.set_visible(True)
            self.status.connect("popup_menu", self.on_right_click)
            self.status.connect("activate", self.set_visible, True)
            self.set_up()

    def main():
        gtk.main()
        return 0

    if __name__ == "__main__":
    ShutdownTimer()
    main()
```

I'm sure i've got some issues going on in my code as far as formatting, commenting, and probably naming conventions but any help shedding light on my issue would be appreciated.. Thank you :)!

Comment: Hi Lonnie, probably nobody is so concerned about naming issues or commenting that it would interfere with their willingness to help you. However, two tips that will help you get a quicker answer: 1) be specific in your question title, not just "I'm having an issue". 2) minimize your code until it is the smallest program that still reproduces your issue. The menu items, submit callback, etc., all just take up space and distract from what is really going on, and make people less likely to read your question.

Comment: thank you for your comment i honestly wasn't actually sure what the problem is or where exactly the issue was or i would've condensed it XD

and coming from java programming a lot of the people though willing to answer complain when you don't follow naming conventions for methods and classes

Comment: I know that you don't always know exactly where the issue is, but my point is that it's worth taking the time to find out before you post. Half the time you will figure out the answer already yourself just by condensing the code!

Comment: Please update the subject of your question. Be more specific. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for wasting anyones time I managed to solve my issue by calling self.set_up() in this specific spot

```
 def set_visible(self, v, visible):
    self.timer_visible = visible
    if self.timer_visible is True:
        self.set_up()
        self.timerui.show_all()
    else:
        self.timerui.hide_all()
```